# Select and display all rows in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, codeigniter-3

I'm novice in Codeigniter framework and I want to ask if is good or it exist another method to display all rows from database in view page.

I have this controller:

```
    class Dashboard extends CI_Controller{

            public function index()
    {

$data['user'] = $this->dashboard_model->get_user_details($this->session->userdata('logged_in'));  

            $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);
```

Model dashboard:

```
class Dashboard_model extends CI_Model{

    public function get_user_details($user_id){

        $this->db->select("*");
        $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
        $result = $this->db->get('users');
        return $result->result_array ();
    }
}
```

And I display in view page like:

`<?php echo $user[0]['id']; ?>
<?php echo $user[0]['username']; ?>`

Code is working, it show me what I want but I don't know if this is a good solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For single user information I would use row_array() or row()

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html

```
<?php

class Dashboard_model extends CI_Model{

    public function get_user_details($user_id){

        $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
        $result = $this->db->get('users');
        return $result->row_array();
    }
}
```

Controller

```
<?php

class Dashboard extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {

        $this->load->model('dashboard_model');

        // Use the users id stored in your session when logged in 
        $userinfo = $this->dashboard_model->get_user_details($this->session->userdata('id'));  

        $data['id'] = $userinfo['id']; 

        $data['username'] = $userinfo['username']; 

        $this->load->view('includes/header', $data);

        }

}
```

Then echo on view

```
<?php echo $username;?> example <?php echo $id;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `return $result->row_array ();` if it returns only single row.

and then in your view file get the data by using : `$user['id'];`

**for multiple rows :**

your solution is fine but you need to add foreach loop and get the data

ex:

```
foreach($user as $usr) {
  echo $usr['id']; echo  "<br/>";
  echo $usr['username'];
}
```

Comment: I need to return more rows not only one.

Comment: I don't need foreach because I have `$this->db->where('id', $user_id);`

Comment: @JohnDoe : please read my answer again. i have put both examples to fetch single or multiple rows.

Comment: I have tried with `return $result->row_array();` but is not show me!

Answer (score 1):

By applying `$this->db->where('id', $user_id);` you will only get results (1) for the user with `$user_id` (not all users) and (2) you will only get results if a user with that id exists in the database. The correct way to get all users, while slightly modifying your function to support returning only one user is as follows:

```
/**
 * @param int $user_id When NULL will return all users
 * @return array
 */
public function get_user_details($user_id = null) {
    $this->db->from('users');
    if (!is_null($user_id)) {
        $this->db->where('id', $user_id);
        $q = $this->db->get();
        if ($q->num_rows() !== 1) {
            return array();
        }
        return $q->row_array();
    } else {
        return $this->db->get()->result_array();
    }
}
```

So to get all users: `$this->dashboard_model->get_user_details()`

To get logged in user: `$this->dashboard_model->get_user_details($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))`

To get a user with id 123: `$this->dashboard_model->get_user_details('123')`

When `$user_id` is blank you can go through results like:

```
if (count($users) !== 0) {
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        echo $user['id'];
        echo $user['username'];
    }
} else {
    echo 'No users';
}
```

When `$user_id` is set you get a single result thus this will work:

```
if (count($users) !== 0) {
    echo $users['id'];
    echo $users['username'];
} else {
    echo 'User with that id does not exist!';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Updated answer :** *As per details provided in commnets*

instead of `return $result->result_array();`  use `return $result->row_array();`

**View :**

```
<?php echo $user['id']; ?>
<?php echo $user['username']; ?>
```

**For fetching multiple rows :**

`return $result->result_array();` will give you array of all the users present in users table.

What you need to do is, access those users in view page using foreach loop.

```
<?php   
foreach ($user as $row) {
    echo $row['id'];
    echo $row['username']; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Please check my Model_dashboard. I have `$this->db->where('id', $user_id);` It not return me all users.

Comment: I have tried with `return $result->row_array();` but is not show me!

Comment: var_dump($result->row_array()); and let me know what you get

Comment: echo $this->db->last_query(); and run query in phpmyadmin, I think you are passing id which doesn't exist in table

Comment: @JohnDoe how can $this->db->where('id',$user_id); give you an array of rows its gonna give you single result because your table will have one user with that id.

Answer (score 0):

In your MODEL

```
class Dashboard_model extends CI_Model{
public function get_user_details($user_id){

return this->db->get_where('users', array('id' => $user_id))->result_array(); //You can use result_array() for more than one row and row_array() only for one row
//If you want to show all rows form database use this return $this->db->get('users')->result(); OR result_array()
}
```

}

In your View

For more than one row use foreach loop

```
foreach($user as $usr){
echo $usr['']; //Add all your database data here like this
}
```